# How to use a for loop to iterate over a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to create a program that uses a for loop. There are two numbers in the for loop. For example 4 and 6. I want the for loop to iterate over 4 six times, the output should be like this:

```
1
2
3
4
1
2
```

Is there a way to do something like this using Python3?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to loop through the numbers `1, 2, 3, 4` repeatedly until you've looped over a total of 6 numbers?

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes .

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to create an iterator that loops over the range 1..4 infinitely:

```
import itertools

for x in itertools.cycle(range(1, 5)):
    print(x)

# output: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 ...
```

Then you can limit this iterator to 6 numbers with [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
looper = itertools.cycle(range(1, 5))

for x in itertools.islice(looper, 6):
    print(x)

# output: 1 2 3 4 1 2
```

Comment: You put way too much effort into this answer.

Comment: @timgeb I saw an opportunity to over-engineer, and I took it :^)

Comment: Special thanks to [Austin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50561012/1222951) for making me remember that `itertools.islice` exists...

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
for i in range (0,6):
    print( i % 4 + 1 )
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Short and to the point and definitely not over-engineered

Comment: Thanks @RonNabuurs, it was... for a few seconds!

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import islice, cycle
print(list(islice(cycle(range(1, 5)), 6)))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Oh my. I completely forget about `islice`. Take my upvote. My answer is horribly over-engineered...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
iterator = 1

for i in range(6):
    if (iterator > 4):
        iterator = 1
    print(iterator)
    iterator+=1
```

Comment: why complicate something so simple like that? That's just a double for loop

Comment: This is what I came up with. If you have a better suggestion you are welcome to submit it.